# ¿Por qué no se ven las imágenes en mi slider?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title></title>

    <style type="text/css">
    /*propiedades del contenedor del slider*/
    *{box-sizing:border-box}
    .slideshow-container{
    max-width: 1000px;
    height: 30rem;
    position:relative;
    margin:auto;
    border: 0.5rem solid black;
   }
   /* imágenes que aparecen por defecto*/
   .mySlides{
    display:none;
   }
   /* estilos para los botones de retroceder y avanzar  */
   .prev, .next{
    cursor:pointer;
    position:absolute;
    width:auto;
    margin-top:-22px;
    padding:16px;
    color:red;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:18px;
    transition:0.6s ease;
    border-radius:0 3px 3px 0;
   }
   /* posición de los botones de la izquierda y de la derecha*/
   .prev{
    right:-80px;
    top:46%;
    border-radius:3px 0 0 3px;
   }
   .next{
    right:-80px;
    top:54%;
    border-radius:3px 0 0 3px;
   }
   /*  hover de los botones de la izquierda y de la derecha */
   .prev:hover, .next:hover{
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
   }
   /* estilo del texto  */
   .text{
    color:red;
    font-size:15px;
    padding:8px 12px;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:8px;
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
   }

   .numbertext{
    color:red;
    font-size:12px;
    padding:8px 12px;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
   }
   /* las animaciones */
   .fade{
    -webkit-animation-name:fade;
    -webkit-animation-duration:1.5s;
    animation-name:fade;
    animation-duration:1.5s;
   }
   @-webkit-keyframes fade{
    from{opacity:.4}
    to{opacity:1}
   }
   @keyframes fade{
    from{opacity:.4}
    to{opacity:1}
   }
   </style>
   <script>
   var slideIndex = 0;
   showSlides();
   function showSlides() {
   var i;
   var slides = 
   document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
   for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
   slides[i].style.display = "none";
   }
   slideIndex++;
   if(slideIndex > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
   slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
   setTimeout(showSlides,2000);
   }
   </script>    
   </head>
   <body>

   <div class="slideshow-container">
    <div class="mySlides fade">
     <div class="numbertext">1 / 3</div>
      <img src="[![image/img1.png][1]][1]" style="width:100%">
     <div class="text">Caption Text</div>
   </div>

   <div class="mySlides fade">
     <div class="numbertext">2 / 3</div>
      <img src="[![image/img2.png][1]][1]" style="width:100%">
     <div class="text">Caption Two</div>
   </div>

   <div class="mySlides fade">
     <div class="numbertext">3 / 3</div>
      <img src="[![image/img3.png][1]][1]" style="width:100%">
     <div class="text">Caption Three</div>
    </div>
    <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094; 
    </a>
    <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095; 
    </a>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: ¿Que es esto? `src="[![image/img1.png][1]][1]"`